# Plot buy or sell only when candle closes

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am developing a pine script indicator for Tradingview, and I would like some help: is there any code or command to make my plotshape command appear only after the candle closes? This would avoid premeditated signals, which can vary before the candle closes, and end up triggering alerts that can change over the candle's time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the historical operator with your condition and the shape will appear on the opening of the next new bar :

```
plotshape(my_condition[1])
```

or you can use `barstate.isconfirmed` along with your condition to have the shape rendered on it's own bar, but on the very last update of the bar

```
plotshape(my_condition and barstate.isconfirmed)
```